# How do I load a file with ResIL?

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

So I am following some tutorials to learn how to use OpenGL (found [here](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/OpenGL/index.php)) and am trying to load an image as found in lesson 6.

The problem which I am running into is that I am unable to load the file. I am getting an IL_INVALID_EXTENTION error code (1291). First the code sample:

```
// Here is the code calling the load function
if (!gTexture.loadTextureFromFile("LazyFooTutorials/texture.png"))
{
    printf("Unable to load texture from file...\n");
    return false;
}

// Here is the code that calls ResIL
bool LTexture::loadTextureFromFile(std::string path) {
    bool textureLoaded = false;

    ILuint imgID = 0;
    ilGenImages(1, &imgID);
    ilBindImage(imgID);

    ILboolean success = ilLoadImage(path.c_str());

    if (success == IL_TRUE)
    {
        success = ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

        if (success == IL_TRUE)
        {
            textureLoaded = loadTextureFromPixels32((GLuint*)ilGetData(), (GLuint)ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH), (GLuint)ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT));
        }

        ilDeleteImages(1, &imgID);
    }

    if (!textureLoaded)
    {
        printf("Failed to load image: %s\n", path.c_str());
    }

    return textureLoaded;
}
```

I thought that ResIL could load png, and I will go and find the ResIL documentation so that I can verify that.

Comment: When you say "unable to load the file", what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate? Do you get errors? Are you sure the path you provide t the file is correct (relative paths depends on where you start the program form).

Comment: I am getting error code 1291 after I call 'ilLoadImage(path.c_str());' which is [IL_INVALID_EXTENSION](http://www-f9.ijs.si/~matevz/docs/DevIL/DevIL%20Manual.pdf).